# about output logic for simple FSM

Tags: verilog

The following is a simple Verilog Example about  a D FF with synchronous enable

```
module d-ff-en_2seg 
(
input wire clk,reset, 
input wire en,
input wire d, 
output reg q
); 
    // signal declaration 
    IU reg r_reg, r_next;
    // body
    // D FF
    always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
        if (reset)
            r_reg <= 1'bO;
        else 
            r_reg <= r_next;
    // next-state logic 
    always @* 
        if (en)
            r_next = d; 
        else 
            r_next = r_reg;
    // output logic 
    always @*
        q = r_reg; 
endmodule
```

My question is why we need the output logic here? Can we ignore it? Just define r_reg as an output reg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Verilog it is perfectly legal and common to use DFFs as outputs.

In VHDL it is illegal to read from output signals.  http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00051.htm

So, in this case, the line "r_next = r_reg;" could be illegal if you converted this line to VHDL and r_reg was an output.

For this reason, RTL coding guidelines that want to be consistent for both verilog and VHDL will insist that all outputs are assigned in a separate "output logic" section.  This would help (a little) if you eventually wanted to rewrite the code in VHDL.

Comment: What about output q, it looks very redundent, what if i replace q with r_reg? what's the reason for q to be defined at first place?

Comment: In Verilog you are right.  Output q is redundant.  You can safely replace q with r_reg.  q is probably only defined in the first place for the stylistic reason in the answer.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz answered this question perfectly. However the Verilog code has used so many Verilog-2001 features that it is unlikely to keep track with the legacy code compatible requirement with VHDL. Some old tools may already feel difficult to understand @* and type definitions in port list.